# how to handle date in the format as 25-jan-24 in python

Tags: python

I have a column EXPIRY_DT in which the dates are in the format - eg: 25-Jan-24

**df_filtered['EXPIRY_DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df_filtered['EXPIRY_DT']) is causing a warning**

UserWarning: Could not infer format, so each element will be parsed individually, falling back to `dateutil`. To ensure parsing is consistent and as-expected, please specify a format.
df_filtered['EXPIRY_DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df_filtered['EXPIRY_DT'])

i tried using:

**df_filtered['EXPIRY_DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df_filtered['EXPIRY_DT'], format='%d-%b-%y')**

but results in the following error:

An error occurred: unconverted data remains when parsing with format "%d-%b-%y": "24", at position 0. You might want to try:
- passing `format` if your strings have a consistent format;
- passing `format='ISO8601'` if your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exactly the same format;
- passing `format='mixed'`, and the format will be inferred for each element individually. You might want to use `dayfirst` alongside this.

ValueError: unconverted data remains when parsing with format "%d-%b-%y": "24", at position 0. You might want to try:
- passing `format` if your strings have a consistent format;
- passing `format='ISO8601'` if your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exactly the same format;
- passing `format='mixed'`, and the format will be inferred for each element individually. You might want to use `dayfirst` alongside this.

Comment: Are you sure all values in your `EXPIRY_DT` column have that same structure, there are no empty vals, etc.? I am unable to replicate the errors and in fact both of the datetime conversion commands from your post worked for me

Comment: Yes i am sure @kevin41

Comment: Try with `errors='coerce'`. Do you get any `NaT` values in your output?

Comment: If you can send your column infos, we can understand if there is a different type or not, and we can try to figure it out. Because your error says some inputs can't converted.

Comment: Specifically, do you have any 4-digit years in the column? If you had a value like `'25-Jan-2024'`, then the error "unconverted data remains ... 24" is just what would be expected. `20` is interpreted as the 2-digit year and the `24` is left over.

Comment: I have checked all the rows. None have '25-Jan-2024' or a blank value @slthrop

Comment: @MuhammedSamedÖzmen only dates are there in the column in the afore mentioned format

Comment: @slothrop there aren't any NaT

Answer (score 1):

I think this is due to the date format in the data i.e. the column EXPIRY_DT.

Try to convert the strings that match the format to dates:

```
df_filtered['EXPIRY_DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df_filtered['EXPIRY_DT'], format='%d-%b-%y', errors='coerce')
```

See which rows in your data have NAT in the EXPIRY_DT column.

```
problematic_rows = df_filtered[df_filtered['EXPIRY_DT'].isna()]
```

If the dates are all correct and yet we are still getting the error clean up the data which I have learned over time helps a lot. Checking for characters and spaces prior to converting, stripping out those little tinkers:

```
df_filtered['EXPIRY_DT'] = df_filtered['EXPIRY_DT'].str.strip()  # Removes leading/trailing spaces
```

df_filtered['EXPIRY_DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df_filtered['EXPIRY_DT'], format='%d-%b-%y', errors='coerce')

See if that helps. Good luck :)

Comment: df_filtered['EXPIRY_DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df_filtered['EXPIRY_DT'] works but issues the warning

Comment: Is it the same warning above or a new one ?

UserWarning: Could not infer format, so each element will be parsed individually, falling back to dateutil. To ensure parsing is consistent and as-expected, please specify a format. df_filtered['EXPIRY_DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df_filtered['EXPIRY_DT'])